# Adding Google Analytics to an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to implement this new method of Google Analytics, I want to conditinally insert this code in the head section **conditionally** in production mode only, any suggestion to how to do this?

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using Rails 2.3 ? You could wrap the snip in an if statement,

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
    <!-- my analytics code -->
<% end %>
```

simple enough.

Answer (score 11):

Google Analytics and Rails in 5 EASY Steps:

If you are in Rails 3, I just found a great solution for doing Google Analytics in Rails apps.

(1) In your Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rack-google_analytics', :require => "rack/google_analytics"
end
```

(2) Bundle Install

(3) In your config/application.rb (put this in the class definition section - careful not to drop it in a module.  I put mine right under "class Application"):

```
if Rails.env == "production"
  config.middleware.use("Rack::GoogleAnalytics", :web_property_id => "UA-0000000-1")
end
```

(4) Initiate your Google Analytics account

(5) Copy and paste that funky web_property_id from Google's supplied code into the code from (3), replacing 'UA-000000-1'

That's it!

I originally found this solution here:
[David Bock Article](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/david_bock/2010/12/google_analytics_and_rails3)

Answer (score 11):

I know this is already answered, but I spent quite a bit of time based on an answer above which seems to be outdated. So I am posting what I did to get Google Analytics working with my Rails 3.0 app.

1) Add the following in your Gemfile

```
group :production do  
  gem 'rack-google-analytics', :require => 'rack/google-analytics'  
end
```

*Note that it is rack-google-analytics and NOT rack-google_analytics. Ditto with the require part*

2) In your config/environments/production.rb file, add the following snippet (replacing the dummy tracker with the google analytics tracker for your website).

```
config.gem 'rack-google-analytics', :lib => 'rack/google-analytics'
config.middleware.use Rack::GoogleAnalytics, :tracker => 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X'
```

3) Run bundle install and start the rails server
4) Sit back and see the analytics flowing in!

Check out https://github.com/leehambley/rack-google-analytics/blob/master/README.md for instructions on how to make it work with sinatra, padrino etc.

Also, the latest copy of the gem uses `:async` option to use asynchronous tracker. The default is true, so you won't need to use this option unless you want to suppress async for some strange reason!

Answer (score 1):

For people coming across this article, be aware this gem supports the traditional google analytics (as opposed to the "newer" aysnc version). [Google Analytics Async](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=161379)

I didn't really see any switches to convert between the 2 types.